How do I rename a certain folder with the same name as the current blender file via python?
How do I rename a certain folder with the same name as the current blender file via python? It also include the suffix textures_

import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from pathlib import Path 

# bpy.data.filepath is the current absolute filepath
current_file = D.filepath

# get the folder you want to rename 
folder_to_rename = Path(r"C:\some\folder")

#convert to a Path object
fp = Path(current_file)

# fp.stem gets just the name without filetype or parent dir
new_dir_name = f"{fp.stem}_textures"

# get the parent directory
parent_dir = folder_to_rename.parent

# make a string for the new path name
new_folder_path = parent_dir.joinpath(new_dir_name)

#rename it
folder_to_rename.rename(new_folder_path)


Thank you very much. Where do I need to place the path of the folder I want to rename?

I made some edits to my script to fit your use case a bit better.
